# Schedule jobs at midnight w.r.t time zones

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, sails-mongo

I have created a web application in which I'm using sails.js framework and mongodb for back-end purpose. I want to implement a cron job running at midnight of each day so that I can calculate previous day's power consumption of a property. This data has to be used for reporting purpose.
The cron job has to run w.r.t properties location, i.e, if 2 properties are located at different time zones, I have to run the job when midnight occurs for each time zone.

Comment: So you have to set your cron job to run at specific local time that is midnight in other timezone. I don't think current cron implementations handles time-zones for you.

Comment: @Puchacz Exactly. Is there an module or package to do so. I can resolve this for single time-zone, but the problem arises when the clients are in multiple time-zones.

Comment: can't you run 2 cron expressions for specific timezones separately? One for T.Z A and second for T.Z B?

Comment: @Puchacz no,it's about just 2 time-zones... if the clients are in more than 3 or 4 TZs, I have trigger the job jobs based on them.